# Haskell - What makes 'main' unique?

Tags: haskell, types, io, compiler-errors, program-entry-point

With this code:

```
main :: FilePath -> FilePath -> IO ()
main wrPath rdPath = do x <- readFile rdPath
                        writeFile wrPath x
```

I got the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type 'IO t0'
            with actual type 'FilePath -> FilePath -> IO()
```

But the file compiles correctly when I change the name of 'main' to something else.

What's so unique about main and why does its type have to be `IO t0`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because the language spec [says so](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/modules.html).

> A Haskell program is a collection of modules, one of which, by convention, must be called `Main` and must export the value `main`. The value of the program is the value of the identifier `main` in module `Main`, which must be a computation of type `IO t` for some type `t` (see Chapter 7). When the program is executed, the computation `main` is performed, and its result (of type `t`) is discarded.

Answer (score 5):

As GolezTrol said, all programs need to know which symbol to start executing when the function is invoked.  Many scripting languages don't require (or just don't need) a `main` routine as they can have statements placed on the top level.  This is not the case for Haskell, C and many others - these languages need a starting location and by convention that is the `main` function (as per the Haskell spec - see Cat's answer).

Notice Haskell's `main` does not accept any parameters that correspond to the program arguments - these are obtained via `System.Environment.getArgs`.

Answer (score 3):

As in C, Java, or C#, `main` is a special identifier in certain contexts that indicates where the program should start.

In Haskell, `main` is defined to have the type `IO a`. You should either give your function a different name, or if you really want it to be the starting point, change its signature and have it read the arguments from the command line with `getArgs`

Although you didn't ask it specifically, `main` is also special in that it is the only function in a Haskell program that can (safely) invoke IO actions. The Haskell runtime treats `main` as special.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, `main` is a function that takes no arguments and returns a value of type `IO a` that is discarded by the runtime. What your error message is saying is that your `main` does not comply with these requirements. This is indeed true, as your `main` receives two parameters.

In order to access command line parameters, use `System.Environment.getArgs`.

Answer (score 1):

> What's so unique about `Main.main`?

Now that Haskell has an [FFI](https://web.archive.org/web/20180702051235/http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/%7Echak/haskell/ffi/ffi.pdf), it's *figuratively* simple:

| This code: | (sort of) | ends up as: |
| --- | --- | --- |
| module Main(main) where main :: IO () ⋮ | ≈ | module Main() where foreign export *"Hmain"* main:: IO () ⋮ |

<sub>(...*"figuratively"*, **not** *"literally"* - making that work is left as an exercise ;-)</sub>

So what makes `Main.main` unique is that it's visible outside Haskell by default, allowing the runtime system to call your Haskell program. For any other Haskell definition, you would need to use the FFI.

---

> Why does its type have to be `IO t`?

Because  in Haskell only values of type `IO ...` (usually referred to as *actions*) can have visible effects e.g. writing to a file. Furthermore, the runtime system can only call `Main.main` correctly if it is an `IO` action.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is ancient, but I figured I should mention that you can name anything you want `main` in a module that is not (explicitly or implicitly) named `Main`. So

```hs
module Foo where
main :: Int -> Bool
main = (>3)
```

will compile just fine. But if you leave out the module header, or use `module Main where ...`, then it won't.