# Haskell import and export

Tags: haskell

I am from zero to Haskell, and I have the following error that can't get away. Basically t2 is trying to use the function `add1` defined in the other module `t1`. So

```
t1.hs-----
module t1 (add1) where
add1 :: Int -> Int
add1 x = x + 1

t2.hs-----
module t2 where
import t1
   add1 2
```

The error always says `parse error on input`t2'`

What's the problem?

Answer (score 6):

Module names should be uppercase, your `t2.hs` file also has some issues, I've modified it so you should be able to run it with `runghc t2.hs` and see some output:

t1.hs

```
module T1 (add1) where
add1 :: Int -> Int
add1 x = x + 1
```

t2.hs

```
module T2 where
import T1
main = do
  let x = add1 2
  putStrLn (show x)
```

Comment: Is it because of lazy evaluation in Haskell that I can directly use `addl 2` to get value 3 in t2? I thought it is like in Racket....

Comment: @freezdom: by language definition, any thing you want done at run time has to be invoked in the main function.  Alternately, you could use ghci to run bits of your code.

Comment: @freezdom: Where would that value of 3 go?  You can declare a new variable: `someGlobalVal = addl 2` or you can have it local to a function like main, as shown.  Just having `addl 2` at some top level not only isn't Haskell but I have no idea what you'd want that to do.

Answer (score 4):

It needs to be uppercase. Make t1 T1, and t2 T2, and it would work

```
t1.hs-----
module T1 (add1) where
add1 :: Int -> Int
add1 x = x + 1

t2.hs-----
module T2 where
import T1
   add1 2
```

Comment: Note, too, that `add1 2` isn't valid; you need something like `main = print $ add1 2`.

Comment: 1. Why can't I use `print $ add1 2` but need to use `main = print $ add1 2` and call main to get the value?
2. I can't directly call main in the same file where it is defined? e.g. I can not call main in the T2 file.. why is that?

Comment: @freezdom: All expressions have to be in a function, much like C or Java and unlike most scripting languages (ex: Perl, Python).  See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258609/haskell-what-makes-main-unique/6258672#6258672).  Also, the main function must be in the Main module, so just remove `module T2 where` from t2.hs or change it to `module Main where`.

Comment: I thought it is like in Racket.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to load module t2 and it should display "3"?

This doesnt work, cause you have to load a module and then execute a command. Either you can load module t1 and execute "add1 2" in your interpreter shell or you can define a new function in t2 which calls "add1 2":

```
t2.hs-----
module t2 where
import t1 
   add1to2 = add1 2
```

Now you can call the funktion add1to2.

Tobias