# Matching types and monads. Error

Tags: haskell

```
type C = StateT Int (ErrorT String IO)


main :: C ()
main = do
  args <- liftIO $ getArgs
  case args of
    [] -> liftIO $ putStrLn "E"
    (p:ps) -> s "d"

s :: String -> C ()
```

I've got the error:

```
     Couldn't match type ‘Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy.StateT
                           Int
                           (Control.Monad.Trans.Error.ErrorT String IO)
                           ()’
                   with ‘IO t0’
    Expected type: IO t0
      Actual type: C ()
    In the expression: main
    When checking the type of the IO action ‘main’
```

I cannot understand why there is an error and how to repair it. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell - What makes 'main' unique?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258609/haskell-what-makes-main-unique)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`main` must be of type `IO a` for some `a` (usually, but not necessarily, `()`). It can't be of type `StateT Int (ErrorT String IO)`. You can fix this by using the functions provided with `StateT` and `ErrorT` for converting them to actions of the underlying monad.

Comment: "You can fix this by using the functions provided with StateT and ErrorT for converting them to actions of the underlying monad.". What do you mean?

Comment: @Gilgamesz E.g., `runStateT` and `runErrorT`.